# using JSON response from REST api with nonstandard names

Tags: c#, json, rest, restsharp

```
{"balances-and-info":{"on_hold":[],"available":    {"USD":0.93033384},"usd_volume":"243.18","fee_bracket":    {"maker":"0.00","taker":"0.60"},"global_usd_volume":"0.09942900"}}
```

I have this JSON response, and I'm trying to store it in an object, however as you can see "balances-and-info" cannot be used as a variable name. The method I have been using is:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient("http://currency-api.appspot.com/api/");
RestRequest request = new RestRequest(url);

var response = client.Execute<Currency>(request);

Currency obj = response.Data;
```

Where obviously the class is a lot easier

```
public class Currency
{
    public string rate { get; set; }
}
```

So how can I handle this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

String.replace() balances-and-info with balances_and_info

in your code

```
YourObject deserialized = parseResponse(obj.replace("balances-and-info", "balances_and_info"));
```

---

```
YourObject parseResponse(string response) {
    try
    {
        // https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/ 
        // Json.NET
        YourObject ret = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObject>(response);
        return ret;
    }
    catch (JsonSerializationException)
    {
        // do something 
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

YourObject

Use http://json2csharp.com/ and generate your object (copy response string, replace balances-and-info with balances_and_info and generate)

```
public class Available
{
    public double USD { get; set; }
}

public class FeeBracket
{
    public string maker { get; set; }
    public string taker { get; set; }
}

public class BalancesAndInfo
{
    public List<object> on_hold { get; set; }
    public Available available { get; set; }
    public string usd_volume { get; set; }
    public FeeBracket fee_bracket { get; set; }
    public string global_usd_volume { get; set; }
}

public class YourObject
{
    public BalancesAndInfo balances_and_info { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Wasn't correct word for word, but you pointed me in the right direction. Got it working - thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it helped, still code misses came from coding directly into browser at 2am :)